# Google Sheets' IMPORTRANGE rows that only contain content

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

In Google Sheets, how to `IMPORTRANGE` rows that only contain content from another spreadsheet

like:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cNtce7pkPlCF6YzpRoDeucSZq9iaiw6K8hILfQ3WHog/","Sheet1")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it could be like this:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1cNtce7pkPlCF6YzpRoDeucSZq9iaiw6K8hILfQ3WHog", "Sheet1!A:D"), 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

which translates as: import range A:D from another spreadsheet from tab called Sheet1 but only if column A is not empty

Comment: like https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14tvmEOQ65zGG0nE5axJuYviELPBL-1OK52sX-WWZY9g/ and https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cNtce7pkPlCF6YzpRoDeucSZq9iaiw6K8hILfQ3WHog/

Comment: try like this: `={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1cNtce7pkPlCF6YzpRoDeucSZq9iaiw6K8hILfQ3WHog", "Sheet1!A:D"), 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0); QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("14tvmEOQ65zGG0nE5axJuYviELPBL-1OK52sX-WWZY9g", "Sheet1!A:D"), 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)}`